# Why do I get only 000000 as the add on number in a PHP Ajax file transfer with add on number?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got help  from stackoverflow but I do get now only 000000 as the add on numbers:

1) I want to Format ID2 to "000000" six digits, example if the ID2 is 302 then should it be "000302"

2) I want to combine the now formatted data  (000302) in    with .$_FILES['file']['name'] in the upload.php file and save the file with this new file name.

The $new_id have always "000000", whatever I do.

I am still lost how to do it, even the first help was very good!

The file transfer code is not from me. It is a code that is from the internet.

I would be very happy for any help!

This is the in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config =
    {
        support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",     // Valid file formats
        form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
        dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
        uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        initMultiUploader(config);
    });

</script>
```

This in the body section:

```
            <div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
            <br>
            <span style="padding-left: 20px">To upload more pictures for this item click Browse</span>
            <br>
            <span style="padding-left: 20px">The order of the upload decide the order to show the pictures</span>

            </div>

            <form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="">
                <input id="ID2" type="hidden" name="ID2">
                <input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
                <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />

            </form>

            <div class="progressBar">
                <div class="status"></div>
            </div>
```

This the file upload.php

```
            <?php
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
                $new_id = sprintf( "%06d", $_POST['ID2']);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "sobimages/" . $new_id . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
                    echo($_POST['index']);
                }
                exit;
            }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a form field in the form that is hidden:

```
<input id="ID2" type="hidden" name="ID2">
```

But it has no value and as the user will not see it and fill in a value, it will always be empty / 0.

You should not use this approach as the user could manipulate the number. If you have the number already available, you should keep it on the server, for example in a session variable, and use that instead.

Comment: Even if I change from type="hidden" to "text" and a number is inside, I get the same result.  I tried it.

But the idea with the session variable is good.

I am still  curious why it does not have a value in the php  file.  in the form is the value to see if I unhide the field.